# is it possible to privately contact a ros answer's user

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is there a way to send a message directly to a ros answer's user?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228136/is-it-possible-to-privately-contact-a-ros-answer%27s-user/) by [chukcha2](https://answers.ros.org/users/25963/chukcha2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-06-06**:
I would like to contact with you, could you facilitate me your e mail or something? It is about something we have in common and think we could help each other, just exchange opinions, does not need a ros answers to be open

**Comment by [chukcha2](https://answers.ros.org/users/25963/chukcha2/) on 2016-06-08**:
sure, it is chukcha2 at yahoo dot com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Contacting individuals directly is actually discouraged in the official [support guideline (see "Do Not" section)](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do_Not).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, no. You can contact one directly if he/she provides additional info on the profile.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2